# D3 Updating ToolTip HTML

Tags: html, d3.js

I have the following HTML

```
                <div id="tooltip" className="hidden">
                   <table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="3">
                                <strong id="headDate"></strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="toolTipBody">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Below the the D3 code that is working fine:

```
                // ToolTip
                d3.select('#tooltip')
                    .classed("hidden", false)
                    .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
                    .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
                    .select('#headDate').text(d0.date);
```

I need to inject/append HTML from D3 to the tool tip into the #toolTipBody element. It needs to be dynamic as the number of lines and names of lines can change (otherwise I could hard code the HTML and just use D3 .select & .text to make the updates.

How would I add say the following to #toolTipBody

```
                        <tr>
                            <td className="legend-color-guide"><div></div></td>
                            <td id="key">1.0E-6MHz</td>
                            <td id="value">46.50</td>
                        </tr>
```

thanks
Adam

[image]

Comment: what is the action that triggers the population of the tooltip (and do you have a mockup or screenshot of your visualization)?

Comment: also, I see that you're using `className` so I'm assuming you're using React?

Comment: Yes using react... I'll add a screenshot... would add all the code but most isn't related.

Comment: Can't you change the content in #toolTipBody, just by selecting it and using text function ?

Comment: Is the tooltip displaying data for all of the displayed lines? What causes the tooltip to display? Hovering over any of the data points at that particular DateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the HTML part dynamically as shown below.

```
 d3.select('#tooltip').html(newHTML);
```

Reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#html

**Demo** - (Mouse over the circle)

```js
var testData = [{
  data: [{
    key: "1.0E-6MHz",
    value: "46.50"
  }, {
    key: "2.0E-6MHz",
    value: "50.50"
  }],
  date: "Apr 10",
  color: "red"
}, {
  data: [{
    key: "1.0E-6MHz",
    value: "46.50"
  }, {
    key: "2.0E-6MHz",
    value: "50.50"
  }, {
    key: "1.8E-6MHz",
    value: "10.50"
  }],
  date: "Feb 19",
  color: "green"
}];

d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(testData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return (i + 1) * 100
  }).attr("cy", 50)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select('#tooltip')
      .classed("hidden", false)
      .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
      .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
      .select('#headDate').text(d.date);

    var newHtml = [];
    d.data.forEach(function(h) {
      newHtml.push('<tr>',
        '<td id="key">' + h.key + '</td>',
        '<td id="value">' + h.value + '</td>',
        '</tr>');
    });

    d3.select('#tooltip')
      .select("#toolTipBody").html(newHtml.join(""))
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select('#tooltip')
      .classed("hidden", true);
  });
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colSpan="3">
          <strong id="headDate"></strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="toolTipBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<svg width=400 height=200>
</svg>
```